# getNOAA.bathy, NOAA server down?

Tags: r

Getting this error message from the following code.

```
library(marmap)
bathy<- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 113, lon2 = 115, lat1 = 4, lat2 = 5,
          resolution = 2)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

The code has worked fine on every other occasion so was wondering if anyone knows if the NOAA ETOPO1 server down? I've emailed the contact on the server website but maybe someone here has an answer in the meantime.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening the URL directly?

Comment: Just did, thanks for the debugging tip Andrew; The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at mapserver.ngdc.noaa.gov Port 80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it and it worked fine for me. For the future, a *404 Not Found* error means that the service can not be found by the server http://www.wikiwand.com/en/HTTP_404. I would just try again in the case it happens again. Their servers may be temporarily down.

To get the URL that the function is using, you could look at the source code, and just copy paste that into a browser adding the parameters you want to see if it's a problem with R or with the HTTP request itself (the HTTP code indicated it wasn't an R problem anyway, but this approach useful for debugging things).

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for the Debugging tip. I tried this morning directly and got;                                                                                                                                 The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at mapserver.ngdc.noaa.gov Port 80

Answer (score 0):

Just updating my suggestion below; I note that MARMAP v0.9.2 has now been rectified for this change in server location and works fine.

John from NOAA replied to me. The URL used in getNOAA.bathy had been retired sometime ago. He suggested I substitute the following URL which I amended into the function with success;

http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/mapviewer-support/wcs-proxy/wcs.groovy?filename=etopo1.xyz&request=getcoverage&version=1.0.0&service=wcs&coverage=etopo1&CRS=EPSG:4326&format=xyz&resx=0.016666666666666667&resy=0.016666666666666667&bbox=-90.08789062497661,22.248428704378167,-79.07958984372954,31.877557643332576

```
getNOAA.bathy2<-
function (lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2, resolution = 4, keep = FALSE) 
{
x1 = x2 = y1 = y2 = NULL
if (lon1 < lon2) {
  x1 <- lon1
  x2 <- lon2
}
else {
  x2 <- lon1
  x1 <- lon2
}
if (lat1 < lat2) {
  y1 <- lat1
  y2 <- lat2
}
else {
  y2 <- lat1
  y1 <- lat2
}
res = resolution * 0.0166666666666667
FILE <- paste("marmap_coord_", x1, ":", y1, ":", x2, ":", 
              y2, "_res_", resolution, ".csv", sep = "")
if (FILE %in% list.files()) {
  cat("File already exists ; loading '", FILE, "'", sep = "")
  exisiting.bathy <- read.bathy(FILE, header = T)
  return(exisiting.bathy)
}
else {
  WEB.REQUEST <- paste("http://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/mapviewer-support/wcs-proxy/wcs.groovy?filename=etopo1.xyz&request=getcoverage&version=1.0.0&service=wcs&coverage=etopo1&CRS=EPSG:4326&format=xyz&resx=0.016666666666666667&resy=0.016666666666666667&bbox=-90.08789062497661,22.248428704378167,-79.07958984372954,31.877557643332576", 
                       res, "&resy=", res, "&bbox=", x1, ",", y1, ",", x2, 
                       ",", y2, sep = "")
  cat("Querying NOAA database ...\n")
  cat("This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size\n")
  bath <- read.table(WEB.REQUEST)
  cat("Building bathy matrix ...\n")
  bath2 <- as.bathy(bath)
  if (keep == TRUE) {
    write.table(bath, file = FILE, sep = ",", quote = FALSE, 
                row.names = FALSE)
  }
  return(bath2)
}
}
```