# Marmap getNOAA.bathy- NOAA server moved/down?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a bathymetric map of the seafloor using getNOAA.bathy in MARMAP.

```
scotia <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1=-42, lon2=-34, lat1=-51, lat2=-55, resolution = 10, keep=TRUE)
```

I know the coding is correct as I successfully ran it at a higher resolution in November, but all I get now is the error...

```
Querying NOAA database ...
This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
Error in getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -42, lon2 = -34, lat1 = -51, lat2 = -55,  : 
The NOAA server cannot be reached
```

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279668/getnoaa-bathy-noaa-server-down/26290231) 
however, it did not work for me. I see that NOAA upgraded their website in December [(as it says here)](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/errors.html) but not sure how to connect this up with the R code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find an answer to my own question through the very helpful people at NOAA.

NOAA did move the page so the web address no longer worked

The updated function is now [here](https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/blob/master/R/getNOAA.bathy.R) although, it took me a while to realise that I needed to call it something different to getNOAA.bathy.

```
getNOAA.bathy <-
function(lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2, resolution = 4, keep=FALSE, antimeridian=FALSE)   {

x1=x2=y1=y2 = NULL

if (lon1 < lon2) {lon1->x1 ; lon2->x2} else {lon1->x2 ; lon2->x1}
if (lat1 < lat2) {lat1->y1 ; lat2->y2} else {lat1->y2 ; lat2->y1}

res = resolution * 0.016666666666666667

fetch <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2,res) {
    WEB.REQUEST <- paste("https://gis.ngdc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/public/wcs/etopo1.xyz?filename=etopo1.xyz&request=getcoverage&version=1.0.0&service=wcs&coverage=etopo1&CRS=EPSG:4326&format=xyz&resx=", res, "&resy=", res, "&bbox=", x1, ",", y1, ",", x2, ",", y2, sep = "")
    dat <- suppressWarnings(try(read.table(WEB.REQUEST),silent=TRUE))
    return(dat)
}

# Naming the file
if (antimeridian) {
    FILE <- paste("marmap_coord_",x1,";",y1,";",x2,";",y2,"_res_",resolution,"_anti",".csv", sep="")
} else {
    FILE <- paste("marmap_coord_",x1,";",y1,";",x2,";",y2,"_res_",resolution,".csv", sep="")
}

# If file exists in the working directory, load it,
if(FILE %in% list.files() ) {
    cat("File already exists ; loading \'", FILE,"\'", sep="")
    read.bathy(FILE, header=T) -> exisiting.bathy
    return(exisiting.bathy)
} else { # otherwise, fetch it on NOAA server

    if (antimeridian) {

        l1 <- x2 ; l2 <- 180 ; l3 <- -180 ; l4 <- x1

        cat("Querying NOAA database ...\n")
        cat("This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size\n")
        left <- fetch(l1,y1,l2,y2,res)
        right <- fetch(l3,y1,l4,y2,res)

        if (is(left,"try-error")|is(right,"try-error")) {
            stop("The NOAA server cannot be reached\n")
        } else {
            cat("Building bathy matrix ...\n")  
            left <- as.bathy(left) ; left <- left[-nrow(left),]
            right <- as.bathy(right)
            rownames(right) <- as.numeric(rownames(right)) + 360
            bath2 <- rbind(left,right)
            class(bath2) <- "bathy"
            bath <- as.xyz(bath2)
        }

    } else {

        cat("Querying NOAA database ...\n")
        cat("This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size\n")
        bath <- fetch(x1,y1,x2,y2,res)
        if (is(bath,"try-error")) {
            stop("The NOAA server cannot be reached\n")
        } else {
            cat("Building bathy matrix ...\n")  
            bath2 <- as.bathy(bath)
        }
    }

    if (keep) {
        write.table(bath, file=FILE, sep=",", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
    }

    return(bath2)
}
}
```

Comment: Or you could have updated marmap to the latest version (0.9.6) published on CRAN the 10th of January to account for this change on NOAA servers...